# What is the NSObject isEqual: and hash default function?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsobject

I have a database model class that is a `NSObject`. I have a set of these objects in a `NSMutableArray`. I use `indexOfObject:` to find a match. Problem is the model object's memory address changes. So I am overriding the `hash` method to return the model's row ID. This however does not fix it. I also have to override the `isEqual:` method to compare the value of the `hash` method.

**What does the `isEqual:` method use to determine equality by default?**

I'm assuming it uses the memory address. After reading the [`isEqual:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:) documentation I thought it used the value from the `hash` method. Obviously, that is not the case as my attempt to override that value did not solve my initial problem.

Comment: There are a few speculative answers here.  Can anyone provide actual documentation that the default isEquals uses address>  I'm not suggesting it doesn't, just would like to hear it from the horse's mouth.

Comment: @DougW I shared your feelings on this, so I tracked down an official reference and edited it into the accepted answer.

Comment: You're reading the docs for the NSObject protocol, not the NSObject class. The protocol defines what the methods should do, the class fails to define what it actually does. It's always safest to override equals and hash to work how you want them to work.

Comment: @TerryWilcox No, it's documented, as is referenced in the accepted answer. It's just not documented in the class reference, where you would expect it. It's absolutely not necessary to override `isEqual:` to perform explicit pointer comparision with `==` just to safely pass `indexOfObject:` an instance of some arbitrary `NSObject` subclass - you can trust that `NSObject`'s `isEqual:` will do pointer comparison.

Comment: @MarkAmery I meant not documented in the class docs, which is where it should be documented. A one line mention in a different document is documentation by accident. And while you can trust that NSObject will do pointer equality, trusting that pointer equality is always sufficient is somewhat risky.

Comment: @TerryWilcox I agree the documentation on this point is embarrassingly poor, but I think suggesting that you should always override `isEqual:` and not trust `NSObject`'s implementation is going too far. Obviously, though, if pointer equality (which is what `NSObject`'s `isEqual:` implementation checks for) isn't actually what you *want*, then you should override it.

Comment: @MarkAmery I didn't say you can't trust NSObject's equals method, I said it's safest to always override it to do what you want. Like making equals compare the primary keys in a database object, rather than hoping your persistence layer caches your objects so well that it never thinks it needs to reload data. You can cross your fingers or you can be explicit. One is safer than the other.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As you've correctly guessed, `NSObject`'s default `isEqual:` behaviour is comparing the memory address of the object. Strangely, this is not presently documented in the [NSObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but it is documented in the [Introspection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introspection/Introspection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH9-SW61) documentation, which states:

> The default `NSObject` implementation of `isEqual:` simply checks for pointer equality.

Of course, as you are doubtless aware, subclasses of `NSObject` can override `isEqual:` to behave differently. For example, `NSString`'s `isEqual:` method, when passed another `NSString`, will first check the address and then check for an exact literal match between the strings.

Comment: A reference for this would be nice.

Comment: ... so I added one. Strangely, the `NSObject` class reference doesn't even have an entry for `isEqual:`, let alone describe its behaviour anywhere, which seems like a glaring omission. I was able to track down an official reference in some obscure page in the 'conceptual' section of the docs, though.

Comment: The Apple documentation is rife with cases where protocol methods are not documented in the class documentation.  (Not to mention superclass methods.)  You often have to look under a lot of rocks to find documentation for a given method.

Comment: (I do wish the Apple documentation was more like Java's, where all of the inherited methods are at least listed with a class's description.)

Answer (score 13):

The answer about default implementation of `isEqual:` is comprehensive one. So I just add my note about default implementation of `hash`. Here it is:

```
-(unsigned)hash {return (unsigned)self;}
```

I.e it's just the same pointer value which is used in `isEqual:`. Here's how you can check this out:

```
NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSLog(@"obj: %@",obj);
NSLog(@"hash: %x",obj.hash);
```

The result will be something like this:

```
obj: <NSObject: 0x16d44010>
hash: 16d44010
```

Best Regards.

BTW in iOS 8 `hash` became a property not a method, but it's there.

Answer (score 5):

I would assume that `NSObject` `isEquals` uses the `==` operator, and `hash` uses the memory address.

`isEquals` method should never uses `hash` as an absolute test for equality.  It is guaranteed to have two objects having similar `hashCode`, if you search for enough objects (just create more than 2^32 different objects, and at least two of them will have the same `hash`).

In other words, `hash` requires the following spec:  If two objects are equals, then their `hash` needs to be equal; however, if two objects' `hash` values are equals, they are not necessarily equal.

As a tip, you always should override `isEquals` and `hashCode` together.