# How to compare 2 objects for equality in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, comparison

In Java you can write an if statement like this:

if(object1.equals(object2)){
   // Do something....
}

How can I code the same logic in Objective-C?
I basically want to compare 2 of any one type of objects, such as 'Text Fields', 'Text Views', etc.

Thank you.

Shakeel

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319247/how-to-compare-if-two-objects-are-really-the-same-object

Answer (score 30):

It's pretty similar!

```
if ([object1 isEqual:object2])
```

see the [`NSObject` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:) documentation.

Comment: Because it's a protocol; there isn't an implementation for it to describe! You need to look at what an implementation of that protocol does - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241575/what-is-the-nsobject-isequal-and-hash-default-function