# iOS - How to handle iPhone's photos whether changed when app become active?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I use a custom `UICollectionView` to display iPhone's photos. I want to reload `UICollectionView` when app become active after user delete/modify/add one or more photos.

I save `PHAsset` in a array, `[previousAssetsArray isEqual:currentAssetsArray]` is not working.

Any idea?

EDIT:

[What is the NSObject isEqual: and hash default function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4253490/6279975)

When I get photos' assets again, its address changed, so `previousAsset` will not equal to `currentAsset` even they belong to a photo. `[previousAsset isEqual: currentAsset]` always `NO`.

I also use the property `hash` of `PHAsset` to check if photos changed. But I found when I just modified(crop) one photo in Photos app, its hash not changed.

Comment: you can compare count values for both "previousAssetsArray" and "isEqual:currentAssetsArray" rather than comparing two arrays.

Comment: @HirenPatel If just modified some photos, I will reload `UICollectionView`, to compare count values will be not working.

Comment: both arrays can have different memory addresses so you can't compare directly. You may have to iterate through array to compare changes or you have to reload collection view overtime app becomes active.

Comment: why don't you reload itself irrespective they are same or not?

Comment: @FahimParkar Because when I reload it even there is nothing changed, reload `UICollectionView `  will cause some animation. That‘s not a good experience.

Answer (score 0):

try this `[previousAssetsArray isEqualToArray:currentAssetsArray]`

Example:: BOOL theyAreEqual = [myFirstArray isEqualToArray:mySecondArray];

if you want to compare count of both array 
  `previousAssetsArray.count == currentAssetsArray .count`

Comment: It seems `PHAsset` can't compare, even is same photo's `PHAsset`. So `isEqualToArray` is not work. If array's objects is string, this method will be work.

Comment: try this once.   for ( int i = 0; i < [previousAssetsArray count]; i++ )
    {
        if ( previousAssetsArray[i] == currentAssetsArray[i] )
        {
            NSLog(@"the same elements in this selection");
        }
    }

Comment: Because I get photos' `PHAsset` again, so `previousAsset` is not equal to `currentAsset` even they belong to one photo. If array's objects is `NSString`, this method is OK.